# Are "getting p.p" and "have been p.p" same?

Tags: passive-voice, subordinate-clauses

I've come across this following sentence:

> He said he's noticed more consumers getting approved since 2010's third quarter[1].

I wonder if I can rewrite it this way:

> He said he's noticed more consumers have been approved since 2010's third quarter.

[1] [www.fraze.it](http://www.fraze.it)

Comment: Why did you tag this as "British"?

Comment: @tchrist Must've been an error while posting however seems a person corrected it

Comment: What was the source of the sentence, Please? Author and publication and a link if possible. See [Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: @DavidSiegel I've seen it on fraze.it if you write part of senstence you could easily find it

Comment: @Kojiama  I am asking **You**, and all posters, to properly attribute any and every quoted example or source that you use in posts on this site.Directing others how to search for your example is insufficient, although better than nothing.  There is a [meta discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/should-we-take-action-on-posts-from-experienced-users-with-uncited-quotes) going on now about this.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I get it now Okay no problem

Comment: The only problem is that the continuous form "getting" is not the same as the simple form "have been."

Comment: @Kojiama if you get it and it's no problem like you said, then link to the source.

Comment: @muru it's done now

Comment: @Kojiama I don't see the quoted text anywhere in the linked page

Comment: @muru search it amongst sentences

Answer (score 4):

'Getting [x]' often describes the *process* of something happening. For example, "I'm wet" describes your current condition, whereas "I'm getting wet" describes what is currently happening to you.

- More "getting approved" sounds like the increase has been in the approval *ratio*.
- More "have been approved" sounds like an increase in either the number of qualifying applications or the efficiency of the approval process.

For example, let's say you receive and process 100 applications a month, of which around 80% are approved, the rest rejected. Saying that you see more approvals could be explained by a number of things including an increase in applications. But let's say that the criteria for approval changed, and now you were able to approve around 90% of the same number of applications. I would say that there an increase in *getting* approval better describes this latter scenario.

Comment: I’m a native speaker and if those suggested connotations are correct it’s news to me. I’m not saying they are wrong. I’m just suggesting that the difference between the two constructions might not be clear even to native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

getting approved is the same as: being approved or receiving approval

both mean the same thing. The approval is ongoing now.

You can rewrite it with the present perfect but there is no need to.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the exact quoted examples, they are the same. However, that is not to suggest that "getting" and "have been" are interchangeable.

For example,

> I have been confused by this movie.

Implies that the confusion occurred in the past but was resolved.

> I am getting confused by this movie.

Means that the confusion is happening in the present and is still ongoing.

The difference is "since 2010’s third quarter" along with the increasing quantity. If we add *since* and a time in the past to the above examples, we get these:

> I have been confused by this movie since I first saw it.

This now means the speaker is still confused, but they are not necessarily getting any more confused.

> I am getting confused by this movie since I first saw it.

That is ungrammatical. It makes no sense because you can’t be progressively getting confused by something in the present when you experienced it only in the past.

So let’s try adding an increasing quantity to our examples:

> I have been paid more and more money since I became a software developer.

And

> I am getting paid more and more money since I became a software developer.

Mean essentially the same thing.